# Cannot scroll horizontally with ScrollView for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am trying to display my advertisement images on horizontally ScrollView, just like the scroll view on the top of App store. The size of the images is 320*180.

My problem is: if I set the frame of the scroll view to 320*568, it works just fine, but if I set it to 320*180 (which it should be), the ScrollView does not scroll any more.

Here is my code:

```
#import "AdsScrollViewController.h"

@interface AdsScrollViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pageImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pageViews;

- (void)loadVisiblePages;
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page;
- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page;
@end

@implementation AdsScrollViewController
@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl = _pageControl;
@synthesize pageImages = _pageImages;
@synthesize pageViews = _pageViews;

- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
    // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
    return;
}

// 1
UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {
    // 2
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

    // 3
    UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]];
    newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    newPageView.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
    // 4
    [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
}
}

- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page {
if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
    // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
    return;
}

// Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull*)pageView != [NSNull null]) {
    [pageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];
}
}

- (void)loadVisiblePages {
// First, determine which page is currently visible
NSLog(@"load visible pages");
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));

// Update the page control
self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

// Work out which pages you want to load
NSInteger firstPage = page - 1;
NSInteger lastPage = page + 1;

// Purge anything before the first page
for (NSInteger i=0; i<firstPage; i++) {
    [self purgePage:i];
}

// Load pages in our range
for (NSInteger i=firstPage; i<=lastPage; i++) {
    [self loadPage:i];
}

// Purge anything after the last page
for (NSInteger i=lastPage+1; i<self.pageImages.count; i++) {
    [self purgePage:i];
}
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.pageImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"ad1.jpg"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"ad2.jpg"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"ad3.jpg"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"ad1.jpg"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"ad2.jpg"],
                   nil];

NSInteger pageCount = 5;//self.pageImages.count;

// 2
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;

// 3
self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
    [self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// 4

[_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * 5, 568);// pagesScrollViewSize.height);
NSLog(@"view will appear");
NSLog(@"%f, %f",self.scrollView.frame.size.height,self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
// 5
[self loadVisiblePages];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
// Load the pages which are now on screen
[self loadVisiblePages];

}

@end
```

Comment: The first thing you should try is removing all of your page loading and purging code, just set the dimensions to 320x180 and manually add a few views. Check if it scrolls. Then add the automatic loading (but not purging) and try again, etc. You'll narrow down your problem code to specific functions, and then you can change your question to "this particular function is causing a scrollview to stop scrolling and I don't know why".

Comment: I've had this problem a few times, and it always got solved by manually setting the scrollView.contentSize to the contentSize of what is being displayed. Please check if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, like you said, that all the images that you want to display are 320x180 or the same aspect ratio, you could change the following code in loadPage:

```
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0.0f;
```

to the following block:

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(320*page, 0 , 320, 180);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*(page+1),180);
```

I believe this should solve this particular problem. However, if you want to have dynamic sizes in pictures, you could have a float variable to keep track of the width of the scrollView and increment accordingly, as and when you add new subviews to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's still not working. As I have set scrollView.contentSize in viewWillAppear function, do you think I should delete them first and then change the codes as you said?